# Extract all <p> tags until <h1> appears? BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract all the `<p>` tags that appear after an `<i>` tag until it comes across a `<h1>` then it repeats again.

Example html code:

```html
<h1><h1>
<p></p>
<i></i>
<p>Need to grab this</p>
<p>Need to grab this</p>
<p>Need to grab this</p>
<p>Need to grab this</p>
<h1><h1>
<p></p>
```

Problem is the `<p>` with "Need to grab this" vary so sometimes there could be one, three or even like 8.
How do I create a loop and grab them all until that next `<h1>` tag again?

I am using BeautifulSoup at the moment.

Here is my current python code:

```
headernum = 0
i = 0

x = soup.find_all("h1")

for i in range(len(x)):
    header = soup.find_all('h1')[headernum]
    name = header.find_all_next('p')[1]
    print(name.text)
    workplace = name.find_all_next('i')[0]
    print(workplace.text)
    abstract = workplace.find_all_next('p')[1].get_text()
    print(abstract)
    i += 1
    headernum += 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over the [`element.next_siblings` iterator](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-siblings-and-previous-siblings); given a starting element, loop over following sibling elements until you hit your end condition:

```
for elem in start.next_siblings:
    if elem.name == 'h1':
        break
    if elem.name != 'p':
        continue
    # it's a <p> tag before the next <h1>
    ...
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''
... <h1><h1>
... <p></p>
... <i></i>
... <p>Need to grab this</p>
... <p>Need to grab this</p>
... <p>Need to grab this</p>
... <p>Need to grab this</p>
... <h1><h1>
... <p></p>
... ''')
>>> start = soup.find('i')
>>> for elem in start.next_siblings:
...     if elem.name == 'h1':
...         break
...     if elem.name != 'p':
...         continue
...     print(elem)
...
<p>Need to grab this</p>
<p>Need to grab this</p>
<p>Need to grab this</p>
<p>Need to grab this</p>
```

Combined with your existing code (slightly polished up):

```
for header in soup.find_all("h1"):
    name = header.find_next_siblings('p', limit=2)[-1]
    print(name.text)
    workplace = name.find_next_sibling('i')
    print(workplace.text)

    abstract = []
    for elem in name.next_siblings:
        if elem.name == 'h1':
            break
        if elem.name != 'p':
            continue
        # it's a <p> tag before the next <h1>
        abstract.append(elem.get_text())

    print('\n'.join(abstract))
```

Comment: Absolutely amazing thank you! So helpful and works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Using `xpath` could solve this like this:

`//h1/following-sibling::p`

This should give you all the `p`s that are siblings of `h1`s.

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking for. They do not want *all* `<p>` tags, they want only those that are between their current tag and the next `<h1>` tag.

Comment: He can use `find` under `h1`, which will give him all `P`s.

Comment: The `<p>` tags are not child nodes of the `<h1>` tag, so no.